# Probability: selection without replacement

Tags: probability

$3$ flashlights were chosen from a box of $20$ flashlights, $5$ of which were defective.

a) all $3$ were good

b) all $3$ were bad

c) only one was bad

b) $\dfrac{5}{20}\cdot\dfrac{4}{19}\cdot\dfrac{3}{18}$

a) $1-(b)$

Now I'm not sure about c), is it just each individual probability multiplied?

But then what if you chose the bad one first then the probability would be 5/20, if you chose is second then it would be 5/19, third 5/18? Which one am I supposed to follow?

Comment: What have you learnt from all your other recent posts?

Comment: is this question related to any of my other questions? please tell me which one and ill look into it. I dont see how it is.

Comment: Can you explain why you think that (a) = 1 - (b)?

Comment: doesnt the rule p(A)=1-p(A^c) apply

Comment: Yes, but the complement of "they are all good" is not "they are all bad" - it is "at least one of them is bad".

Comment: Let B stand for bad, G for good. For (c) one way is to finf the probability of BGG, GBG, GGB and add up. Tor example BGG has probability $(5/20)(15/19)(14/18)$.

Comment: Your solution for b is fine.  Your solution labeled a is the chance that at least one was good, not that exactly one was bad.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align}\text{a) }P(3\text{ good of }3)&=P(1\text{ good of }1)P(2\text{ good of }2|1\text{ good of }1)P(3\text{ good of }3|2\text{ good of }2)=\\&=\dfrac{15}{20}\cdot\dfrac{14}{19}\cdot\dfrac{13}{18}\end{align}$

$\begin{align}\text{b) }P(3\text{ bad of }3)&=P(1\text{ bad of }1)P(2\text{ bad of }2|1\text{ bad of }1)P(3\text{ bad of }3|2\text{ bad of }2)=\\&=\dfrac{5}{20}\cdot\dfrac{4}{19}\cdot\dfrac{3}{18}\end{align}$

$\begin{align}\text{c) }P(1\text{ bad  of }3)&=P(\text{BGG})+P(\text{GBG})+P(\text{GGB})=\\&=\dfrac{5}{20}\cdot\dfrac{15}{19}\cdot\dfrac{14}{18}+\dfrac{15}{20}\cdot\dfrac{5}{19}\cdot\dfrac{14}{18}+\dfrac{15}{20}\cdot\dfrac{14}{19}\cdot\dfrac{5}{18}\end{align}$

Comment: ok i see where i went wrong on a) and on c) you chose all the possibilities of having a bad one then added then probs together. Thanks.